# Android notification not displayed

Tags: android

I am trying to implement custom notification in android. Following is the code which I am using.
manger.notify() is called successfully but notification is not displayed.
And setCustomBigContentView() is available from N so what should I use for the previous versions? What is wrong I am doing?

compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29

```
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 140683;
private static final String PRIMARY_CHANNEL = "PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID_NOTER";
private static final String PRIMARY_CHANNEL_NAME = "PRIMARY_NOTER";

private void createNotification (Context context) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = createRemoteViews(context,
            R.layout.notification_custom_big_content, R.drawable.ic_phonelink_ring_primary_24dp,
            "Custom notification", "This one is a little bigger!",
            R.drawable.ic_priority_high_primary_24dp);

    Notification.Builder builder = createCustomNotificationBuilder(context);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        builder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
                .setStyle(new Notification.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());

        showNotification(context, builder.build(), NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }

}

private void showNotification(Context context, Notification notification, int id) {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) 
              context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, 
              PRIMARY_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setSound(null, null);
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    manager.notify(id, notification);
}

private RemoteViews createRemoteViews(Context context, int layout, int iconResource,
                                      String title, String message, int imageResource) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layout);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.image_icon, iconResource);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_title, title);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_message, message);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.image_end, imageResource);
    return remoteViews;
}

public Notification.Builder createCustomNotificationBuilder(Context context) {
    return new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_phonelink_ring_primary_24dp)
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND | DEFAULT_VIBRATE) 
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
}
```

Comment: Because your method `showNotification` is called inside this block of code `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)` means that notifications will not be shown for sure in any pre `N` Android version

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this. Answering it if anybody makes such a silly mistake.
Instead of using Notification.Builder I have to use NotificationCompat.Builder.
Once I used NotificationCompat then there was no need of following statement.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){ //This is not required anymore
}
```